# MVC 4 Razor: Using @Html in @Section element causes compilation error

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Disclaimer: I'm brand new to Razor. I can't seem to figure out the following:

When I use @Html element inside @Section, I get the following compilation error

An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation.

Here is my Code:

```
@section login{
@using (Html.BeginForm(new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        @*<fieldset>
            <legend>Log in Form</legend>

                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)

                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new {@class = "checkbox"})
                </li>

            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
        </fieldset>*@
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to put these elements inside html tags, but I've commented a lot of it to troubleshoot. Any input on why I'm getting this error and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a `model` declaration missing

Comment: Is the view this is in strongly-typed? (i.e. has a `@model` directive). You can't use the expression-based methods with a dynamic model (i.e. what you get without an explicit model declaration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your model class (fully namedspaced) as a `@model` directive at the top of your view.

e.g.

```
@model myapplication.mynamespace.LoginModel
```

and your LoginModel looks like:

```
  public class LoginModel
  {
      public string UserName {get; set;}
      public string Password {get; set;}
      public bool RememberMe {get; set;}
  }
```

`TextBoxFor`, `CheckboxFor` etc use expression trees and reflection to get at the real value. Without a real model it has no clue what type of values to expect and therefore can't build an expression tree *at compile time*.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. What I was trying to do was take the code from a Login cshtml file that had its @model property set to a Login model. The thing is, I want to use the logic from the Login view/controller on Index(the home page). Any suggestions on how to use a current functioning view from the Index view?

Comment: Is there a model on your index view already? If not simply add one and make sure the `index` action method in the controller creates a `new LoginModel` and passes it as the ViewModel e.g. `return View(new LoginModel());` or similar

Comment: The `Login` logic really belongs in a partial view so you can render it where you like. If you render it with `@Html.Action("Login", "account")` it will use the account controller.

Comment: So, do you think this should be done from _Layout view or from Index view?

Comment: "Do you want it on all screens?" is the usual question to ask yourself for "does in go into _layout?" :)